# Cleanly deleting an entity in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to delete an entity which is added to the context without saving the changes. I am getting FK constraint errors. The entity is temporary which need not to be saved to the database.

This is how I am adding the entity

```
var productSalesRight = new ProductSupplierSalesRight
                            {
                                Product = product,
                                ProductId = product.ProductId,
                                SalesRightTypeId = countries.FirstOrDefault().SalesRightTypeId,
                                SalesRightType = countries.FirstOrDefault().SalesRightType,
                                Countries = ct
                            };

product.ProductSupplierSalesRights.Add(productSalesRight);
```

This is what I am doing in my code to delete

```
 _context.Entry(productSalesRight).State = EntityState.Deleted;
 product.ProductSupplierSalesRights.Remove(productSalesRight)
```

Is there a right way of deleting an entity?

Answer (score 0):

You should detach your temporary entity record if you don't want to continue inserting it to the database.

Refer to [ObjectContext.Detach Method (Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.detach(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
_context.Detach(productSalesRight);
```